# how to add percentage sign on out put on KUSTO

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to add the % sign on MAX and MIN output on KUSTO. how I can do that if possible.
example:

From

```
             Date        time             source      MAX     Min
             8/27/2020, 12:00:00.000 PM C4592E37E9A   19.43 14.91       
             8/21/2020, 1:00:00.000 PM  2E3437E9A5C   31.97 16.37
```

To

```
            Date        time             source        MAX         Min
            8/27/2020, 12:00:00.000 PM  C4592E37E9A   19.43%      14.91%        
            8/21/2020, 1:00:00.000  PM  2E3437E9A5C   31.97%      16.37%
            

   query:::
   on TimeGenerated, Resource
  | summarize in_Gbps = max(MaxInBps)/10000000000* 100, out_Gbps = 
     max(MaxOutBps)/10000000000 * 100 by bin(TimeGenerated, 60m), Resource
```

so I need the output of in_Gbps/out_Gbps to have "%"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `strcat()`.

for example:

```
print p1 = 75.56
| extend p2 = strcat(p1, "%")
```

```
--------------
p1    | p2
--------------
75.56 | 75.56%
--------------
```

Comment: Thanks, Yoni!! works as expected but I have one related question. why the percentage now IN = 19.436226979999998% OUT 2.68849818%?  as a percentage only 1 or 2 digits after the (.) as your example.  did I miss something or I need to do it?

Comment: I used `75.56` just as an example. please clarify the question regarding it